# pathIsTooLong is not returned from createUploadSession api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

When we try to upload file to specified folder over maximum path length, the following error occurs from createUploadSession api.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "One of the provided arguments is not acceptable.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "...",
      "date": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

We expect to include "pathIsTooLong" code in error response body then.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/errors#error-resource-type

Is this correct behavior?

About CreateUploadSession API
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_createuploadsession

Answer (score 0):

According to your descriptions, you want to include "PathIsTooLong" in error response body.

We can post a suggestion here Url: https://todo.uservoice.com/.